# Unable to add a timestamp to a logger in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

My logger:

```
 logging.basicConfig(filename="{}/log.log".format(config.log_dir), level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", datefmt="%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S"    )
```

And .. no timestamp is getting added:

```
logging.info("fdsfdsfds")
# => fdsfdsfds
```

Comment: Well, the same two lines worked for me, so I guess you maybe have some other place in your code where you change logging config? You can inspect the configuration on default handler once you get it by calling `logging.getLogger()`. Check if it has proper handlers and formatters.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

> That's [my output](http://prnt.sc/dw8iie)

```
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(message)s'
DATE = '%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(filename="log.log",level=logging.DEBUG,format=FORMAT,datefmt=DATE)
logger = logging.getLogger('Stackoverflow log')
logger.info('Info 1')
```

**If you still get no timestamp please add more code**